# What's the etymology of the Russian verb "иметь"?

Tags: этимология

What's the etymology of the Russian verb "иметь"?

What is its root ("-им-" or "-име-")?

What was the root's meaning originally?

Answer (score 6):

It's a PIE [root](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Italic/em%C5%8D) *h₁em- ‎(“to take, distribute”) from which - as you can see from this [link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emo#Latin) - were derived among other words, such as: Lithuanian im̃ti, Old Church Slavonic имѫ ‎(imǫ) and possibly Old Armenian իմանամ ‎(imanam).

The Slavonic [form](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) *jьmǫ: jęti among other words [produced](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F) `иметь`, `взять`, `снять`, `изъять`.

Actually there's more - a lot of verbs ending with [-нять](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) share the same origin.

Comment: Just curious: `*jьmǫ: jęti` are two different words, one older than the other, or they are forms of the same word like "взять, взятый"? I've managed to find transcription rules of Proto-Slavic [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA). The same article also says that *jęti is the passive participle from *jętъ but does not say what *jętъ means.

Comment: @farfareast: _*jьmǫ_ is first person singular present (*по-йму*), _*jęti_ is an infinitive (*по-нять*), _*jętъ_ is a singular past passive participle (*по-нят*).

Comment: @Quassnoi: Thank you! But why is "по-" added in your answer to the root. To show the verb in perfective aspect?

Comment: @farfareast: because the bare imperfective word (*имати*) in the modern language is replaced with a suppletive *иметь* (except in set phrases like *мёртвые сраму не имут*), which conjugates slightly differently. It's *иму, яти* and *ят* for that matter, but those would have risen more questions had I used them.